# Replacing "|" with ","

Tags: r

I have a "|" separated dataset which I am not able to import in R as such and hence I am trying to convert all "|" to "," so that I can import the dataset as csv.

I tried doing this

```
gsub("|", ",", Dataset$V1)
```

But the replacement is done wrong by R. For example if I have

```
string|a|b
```

I want it to be

```
string,a,b
```

But it is getting converted to

```
s,t,r,i,n,g,|,a,|,b
```

What is the solution ?

Please suggest even if there are any way to import the "|" separated .DEL file in R.

Comment: You need to escape the pipe... `gsub('\\|', ',', 'string|a|b')`

Comment: Thank you .. is there any way to import "|" separated .DEL file in R ? please suggest if there is any option for that too. Thanks

Comment: `read.table(text = "string|a|b", sep = "|")` could work for you.

Comment: No that's just an example I have a dataset full of "|" separated values